# Локальная сеть

Tags: сеть, lan, ethernet

Есть 2 компьютера, их нужно соединить в одну локальную сеть, НО - ни DHCP, ни ручное вбивание айпишек не помогает, сеть "Неизвестная сеть, без подключения к интернету". Инет есть в одном из компьютеров - 3G модем с динамическим айпи. Собственно, как починить?

Comment: Что, гхм, находится между двумя машинами? Если стандартный патчкорд, то они и не увидят друг друга никогда.

Comment: А почему? что должно быть между ними?

Comment: @EugMirk, патчкорд осуществляет связку машина - концентратор. Для связки машина-машина нужен crossover-кабель. В принципе, он ничем не отличается кроме порядка контактов на одном из концов, при наличии лишней вилки и обжимных клещей ситуацию можно исправить за пять минут.

Comment: Дополню, что современному оборудованию абсолютно без разницы каким кабелем его соединять: "прямым" или "crossover'ом". При необходимости оборудование само определяет тип кабеля и "переворачивает" необходимые контакты. Правда, это работает далеко не в 100% случаев.

Answer (score 2):

Пробовали делать ping между машинами?

Если ping проходит, значит сеть между компьютерами вам создать получилось, но просто наличие сети между компьютерами не означает наличия интернета на втором компьютере. Нужно на компьютере, к которому подключается модем, зайти в "Изменение параметров адаптера" и в свойствах модема во вкладке "Доступ" поставить галочку "Разрешить другим пользователям сети использовать подключение к Интернету данного компьютера" и выбрать сеть, в которую вы "транслируете" интернет, у вас это скорее всего "подключение по локальной сети". Описанная инструкция справедлива для Win 7 и выше.